# Dividing a single number by count of rows in each grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 10 groups total.  The grouping numbers (Column `A`) restart at 1 at every distinct value in column `Type`.  I want to divide 100 by the 10 total groups across all types, then the resulting figure per group by number of entries(rows) in each grouping.

Column `A + Type` is my group identifier, column `B` is what I want the final result to look like.

I tried some variations equations based off of nesting queries with counts grouped by `A` and `type`, but I'm not getting my head around how to pull it all together.

```
ID  A   B   TYPE

01  1   10  APPLE
02  2   5   APPLE
03  2   5   APPLE
04  3   2.5 APPLE
05  3   2.5 APPLE
06  3   2.5 APPLE
07  3   2.5 APPLE
08  4   5   APPLE
09  4   5   APPLE
10  5   10  APPLE
11  1   5   ORANGE
12  1   5   ORANGE
13  2   10  ORANGE
14  3   5   ORANGE
15  3   5   ORANGE
16  4   2.5 ORANGE
17  4   2.5 ORANGE
18  4   2.5 ORANGE
19  4   2.5 ORANGE
20  5   10  ORANGE
```

Comment: what should the result look like?

Comment: How `divide 100 by the 10 total groups` give you `10, 5, 5, 2.5, 2.5` ?

Comment: @vkp `colum B` is the desire output.

Comment: I think you should change `Column A + TYPE is my group identifier`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you're right, I will edit

Comment: @pancho018 A bunch of stuff that didn't work.  I didn't include it in the post because I thought it would make an already semi-incoherent question more muddled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

To fix aditional row

```
21  5   **  ORANGE
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42d7e/6)

```
WITH subGroup as (
   SELECT [TYPE], [A], count([TYPE]) as total
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY [TYPE], [A]
),
totalGroup as (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT [TYPE] + CAST([A] as varchar(10))) as total
    FROM Table1        
)
SELECT t.ID, t.[A], (100.0 / tg.total / s.total) as [B], t.[TYPE]
FROM Table1 t
inner join subGroup s
  on t.[Type] = s.[Type]
 and t.[A] = s.[A]
, totalGroup tg
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | A |   B |   TYPE |
|----|---|-----|--------|
|  1 | 1 |  10 |  APPLE |
|  2 | 2 |   5 |  APPLE |
|  3 | 2 |   5 |  APPLE |
|  4 | 3 | 2.5 |  APPLE |
|  5 | 3 | 2.5 |  APPLE |
|  6 | 3 | 2.5 |  APPLE |
|  7 | 3 | 2.5 |  APPLE |
|  8 | 4 |   5 |  APPLE |
|  9 | 4 |   5 |  APPLE |
| 10 | 5 |  10 |  APPLE |
| 11 | 1 |   5 | ORANGE |
| 12 | 1 |   5 | ORANGE |
| 13 | 2 |  10 | ORANGE |
| 14 | 3 |   5 | ORANGE |
| 15 | 3 |   5 | ORANGE |
| 16 | 4 | 2.5 | ORANGE |
| 17 | 4 | 2.5 | ORANGE |
| 18 | 4 | 2.5 | ORANGE |
| 19 | 4 | 2.5 | ORANGE |
| 20 | 5 |   5 | ORANGE |
| 21 | 5 |   5 | ORANGE |
```

Comment: This seems close, but is there a way to make tg.total be the sum of the max of column A of each type rather than the rowcount of each type?  Sorry, I probably didn't explain it very well.  So if there were 35 rows in ORANGE but still in groups 1 to 5 in Column A, it would still be 100.0 / 10 / s.total

Comment: You could update the sqlfiddle demo with new data and try if that match your requirement. If you get an error post the fiddle here and I will take a look. I think would work because I dont hard code `10` my count will get `35`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42d7e/1  here's an example; I just added 1 more row in Orange with a value of 5 in column A.  There are now 2 values of 5 in column A with type Orange instead of 1, so the column B value of 10  should now be a value of 5 in row 20 and the new row 21 because it's dividing 10/2 now instead of 10/1.  Everything else should stay the same except those 2 rows.

Comment: What value should have 20 and 21 rows for `B` ?

Comment: They should both be 5.  100 divided by the 10 groups in column A; 10 a piece in the 10 groups (rows 1, 2-3, 4-7, 8-9, 10, 11-12, 13, 14-15, 16-19, 20-21) divided by the counts  within those groups.

Comment: But If you add one more you now have 11 groups in column A?(no 10)

Comment: Oh. 10 group mean between all the data? I tougth was 10 because each type had 10 rows.

Comment: yes, it's all the data; I would have used incremental values in column A to make it clearer, but I wanted to stay true to the original data since column A restarts at 1 with every new distinct value in Type.

Comment: You shouldnt use 10 or 100 that make it hard to see the pattern, is better if you use 3, 5 or 7 to make the pattern more obvious.  Or include an aditional column. Should column B add to 100 ?

Comment: Yes, I see now it looks too confusing.  column B should add up to 100 no matter how many rows.

Comment: Done, check new query, The change is how you calculate the `totalGroup`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this query helps

```
Select At.A, B = CAST(tot as float) / Cnt, At.Type 
From Test AT
Inner Join 
    (Select A, Type, Cnt = Count(*) From Test
    Group By A, Type) BT On AT.A = BT.A and AT.Type = BT.Type
Inner Join 
    (Select Type, Tot = Count(A) From Test
    Group By Type) CT On CT.Type = AT.Type`
```

Comment: use 4 spaces before each line so text appear on `code` format

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windowing functions to do this, if your SQL Server is 2008+:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    A,
    (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TYPE))/(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A,TYPE)) as B,
    TYPE
FROM <table>
order by TYPE, A asc
```

---

Editing to add: I don't really understand the "Divide 100 by..." part but the math here matches your desired results... so I assume it works out the same, right?

Comment: Cast(Count(*) as float)     order by TYPE, A asc

Comment: Added that! Thanks @pancho018

Comment: I think you are asuming there are 10 rows for each type? In my case I use the 100, but count the total rows for each type.

Comment: Oh! ok.. .that was just a coincidence then... I will update with that logic, still using windowing functions, because I think that's a good way to go about it here.

Comment: And perhaps I'm still misunderstanding the question, but I think some variation of this will work.

Comment: the divide by 100 part is an allocation.  The distinct values in Column A by each type (5 in Apple + 5 in Orange) are each an equal share of the 100.  That allocation of 10 must then be divided by the count of values in A + Type.  e.g. there's 4 values with A = 3 and Type = Apple, so 10/4.